# foreach..dopar runs significantly slower on Docker vs local laptop

Tags: r, foreach, runtime, doparallel

I am currently running into a weird issue that the `foreach...dopar` runs like 10x faster in my local laptop (Dell laptop, Windows 10 OS) with 15 cores than when the R code was put onto Docker container containing 8 cores. The code itself only sets the `ncores` parameter to be `3`, so I am puzzled by why there is such a drastic difference in runtime like that. Did anyone here run into the similar issue with the `doParallel` package in Docker? If yes, how did you resolve it?

Comment: Some functions run by default multithreaded, which may become a bottleneck in parallel operations, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58122571/why-does-the-following-for-loop-utilize-all-of-the-cores-in-my-machine-in-r/58138505#58138505

Comment: If that is the case, shouldn't that apply to the local run as well? Why it only occurs in Docker though?

Comment: Can anyone please give some help on this issue? Do you think it has anything to do with running parallel computing in Rstudio on AWS's S3/datalake?